# How to check for neighbors in Game of Life C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I am working on an assignment for school and of course I receive very vague feedback on our code. The code I am working on is for Conway's Game of Life. I know I am super close. I have code that prints out the new generation but it's definitely not the correct one. It seems it is not counting the neighbors correctly - what should be identified as an alive neighbor doesn't seem to happen.

From our assignment as well (seeing examples of generations being formed) I notice the border cells do change which means I have to access them without going out of bounds. I feel I have been fruitless in my attempts to do this and I think I'm just missing something super obvious.

Please, any feedback would be amazing.
I have several print lines in attempts of debugging.

```cpp
void gameOfLife(vector<vector<string>> &originalGrid, vector<vector<string>> &grid, int row, int col,
                int Rows, int Cols){

    //counts # of alive neighbors
    int aliveNeighbors = 0;
    string alive = "*";

    for(int posX = row-1; posX <= row+1; posX++){
        for(int posY = col-1; posX <= col+1; posX++){

            std::cout << "I am in function - nested loop " << row << " " << col << std::endl;

            if(posX == row && posY == col){

                continue;
            }
            else if((posX >= 0 && posX < Rows) && (posY >= 0 && posY < Cols)){

                std::cout << "I am in function - nested loop - else if " << row << " " << col << std::endl;

                if(grid[posX][posY] == alive){

                    aliveNeighbors++;
                    std::cout << "alive neighbors: " << aliveNeighbors << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /*
        //top cell
        if(grid[row][col-1] == "*"){

            std::cout << "top cell " << row << " " << col << std::endl;
            aliveNeighbors++;
        }
        //bottom cell
        if(grid[row][col+1] == "*"){

            std::cout << "bottom cell " << row << " " << col <<  std::endl;
            aliveNeighbors++;
        }
        //left cell
        if(grid[row-1][col] == "*"){

            std::cout << "left cell " << row << " " << col <<  std::endl;
            aliveNeighbors++;
        }
        //right cell
         if(grid[row+1][col] == "*"){

            std::cout << "right cell " << row << " " << col <<  std::endl;
            aliveNeighbors++;
        }
        //top left
        if(grid[row-1][col-1] == "*"){

            std::cout << "top left cell " << row << " " << col <<  std::endl;
            aliveNeighbors++;
        }
        //top right
         if(grid[row+1][col-1] == "*"){

            std::cout << "top right cell " << row << " " << col <<  std::endl;
            aliveNeighbors++;
        }
        //bottom left
         if(grid[row-1][col+1] == "*"){

            std::cout << "bottom left cell " << row << " " << col <<  std::endl;
            aliveNeighbors++;
        }
        //bottom right
         if(grid[row+1][col+1] == "*"){

            std::cout << "bottom right cell " << row << " " << col <<  std::endl;
            aliveNeighbors++;
        }

    */
        //test cases

        //test case 1: Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies (as if by underpopulation).
        if(grid[row][col] == alive && aliveNeighbors < 2){

            originalGrid[row][col] = ".";
        }

        //test case 2: Any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies (as if by overpopulation/overcrowding).
        if(grid[row][col] == alive && aliveNeighbors > 3){

            originalGrid[row][col] = ".";
        }

        //test case 3: Any live cell with two or three live neighbors lives, unchanged, to the next generation.
        if(grid[row][col] == alive && (aliveNeighbors == 3 || aliveNeighbors == 2)){

            originalGrid[row][col] = grid[row][col];

        }

        //test case 4: Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors will come to life (as if by reanimation or birth).
        if(grid[row][col] == "." && aliveNeighbors == 3){

            originalGrid[row][col] = alive;
        }

        //prints updated grid
        for(int i = 0; i < Rows; i++){
             for(int j = 0; j < Cols; j++){

                std::cout << originalGrid[i][j] << " ";
             }
            std::cout << std::endl;
           }

           std::cout << std::endl;


    return;
}

int main() {

    int rows, col, numOfGen;
    std::cin >> rows >> col >> numOfGen;

    string cell;

    vector<vector<string>> game;

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){

        vector<string> temp;

        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){

            std::cin >> cell;
            temp.push_back(cell);

        }
        game.push_back(temp);
    }

    vector<vector<string>> firstGen;
    firstGen.insert(firstGen.end(),game.begin(),game.end());


    if(numOfGen == 0){

        std::cout << "numOfGen == 0" << std::endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){

                std::cout << game[i][j] << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }


    for(int g = 0; g <= numOfGen; g++){
        for(int i = 1; i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < col; j++){

                gameOfLife(game, firstGen, i, j, rows, col);
            }
        }

        if(g == numOfGen){

           for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
             for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){

                std::cout << game[i][j] << " ";
             }
            std::cout << std::endl;
           }
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to make a function to count the alive neighbors.

Comment: So, the main function receives two vectors as parameters, and it initializes one of the vector's contents, presumably the next generation, based on the other vector's contents, that's presumably the current generator. And, in the main function, I see this function getting called, with the same set of vectors, over and over again. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I fixed the issue where I was actually running for numOfGen+1 rather than just numOfGen.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `firstGen` never gets updated, so you're just computing the first generation over and over. So your output is probably correct for a single generation, but it's the same for any number of generations. Also, check the conditions on your main driver loop: with `for(int g = 0; g <= numOfGen; g++)` the loop executes `numOfGen+1` times.

Comment: Thank you for catching this. I did fix it to say: for(int g = 0; g < numOfGen; g++). When I check the first generation against the example given for the assignment, it is still killing/re-animating cells that shouldn't. It seems like my core issue is when checking for aliveNeighbors - something is amiss there that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Use your debugger. Make a much smaller matrix. You can even print it each time to aide in the debugging. One problem I see without getting too deep into your code is your detection of neighbors looks like it can go out of bounds.